# Matching elements by property ends with in WebDriverIO

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver-io

I am used to Selenium WebDriver were I can do something like this:

`ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> magicPills = _webDriver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("span[id$='_Blue_Pills']"));`

How do I do the same thing in WebDriverIO? I couldn't find anything in the docs that stated `StartsWith`, `EndsWith`, or whatever.

My first failed attempt is:

```
const magicPills = $('span.$_Blue_Pills');
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try as like below in wdio:

```
const magicPills = $$('span[id$='_Blue_Pills']');
```

`$()` returns a webElement not elements
and you can use the same cssSelector you tried in selenium_webdriver(because wdio will automatically resolves to cssSelector internally).

Please try the above and see if it works.